# Hook in oauth2 code with DRF

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build an app which has user login and signup functionality.
I can create login and signup both from django, and DRF but could not hook in oAuth2 with DRF to make it functional.
I have no idea where should i use it.
Should I generate token on signup or login?
How can I make it functional?

Here is my code

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User


class UserCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    email = EmailField()
    username =  CharField()
    first_name = CharField(required=False)
    last_name = CharField(required=False)
    password = CharField()
    confirm_password = CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'password',
            'confirm_password'
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}


    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data['username']
        first_name = validated_data['first_name']
        last_name = validated_data['last_name']
        email = validated_data['email']
        password = validated_data['password']
        confirm_password = validated_data['password']
        user_obj = User(
                username = username,
                first_name = first_name,
                last_name = last_name,
                email = email
            )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save()
        return validated_data



class UserLoginSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    username = CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            # 'email',
            'password',
            # 'token',

        ]
        extra_kwargs = {"password":
                            {"write_only": True}
                            }
    def validate(self, data):
        return data
```

**views.py**

```
class UserCreateAPI(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

class UserLoginAPI(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        print('data',data)
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            new_data = serializer.data
            if new_data:
                try:
                    user = User.objects.get(username=data['username'])
                    print ('user',user)
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    return HttpResponse("Can't find this user")
                login(request, user)
            return Response(new_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**tools.py**

```
def get_token_json(access_token):
    return JsonResponse({
        'access_token':access_token.token,
        'expires_in':datetime.now() + timedelta(days=365),
        'token_type':'Bearer',
        'refresh_token':access_token.refresh_token.token,
        'scope':access_token.scope
    })


def get_access_token(user):
    application = Application.objects.get(name="Foodie")
    try:
        old_access_token = AccessToken.objects.get(user=user, application=application)
        old_refresh_token = RefreshToken.objects.get(user=user, access_token=old_access_token)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse('Have not set any token')
    else:
        old_access_token.delete()
        old_refresh_token.delete()
    new_token = generate_token()
    refresh_token = generate_token()
    access_token=AccessToken.objects.create(user=user, application=app, expires=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=365),token=new_token)
    RefreshToken.objects.create(user=user, application=app, token=refresh_token, access_token=access_token)
    print('aceess',AccessToken)
    return get_token_json(access_token)
```

**How can i bridge the gap between DRF and oAuth2 to make login and user registration functional?**

Answer (score 0):

Try using python social auth.

Add `social.apps.django_app.default` to `INSTALLED_APPS`

Add `social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2` to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`

Add `url(r'^auth/', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social'))` to your `urls.py`

However this will work if you have session authentication in your app. If you want to use token based only, then either add a pipe to create the token and send it or take a look at https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

Comment: I want user login and registration from mobile app. so i need token one. Thanks for your answer.